# Order in execution of multiple string methods in Python

Tags: python, string, function, methods

I realised when I run the below code,

```
teststr='this is a test string btw'
print(teststr.split().upper())
```

it fails with below error message,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\string_properties.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(teststr.split().upper())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

but when I rearranged the order of methods,

```
teststr='this is a test string btw'
print(teststr.upper().split())
```

it works fine.

```
['THIS', 'IS', 'A', 'TEST', 'STRING', 'BTW']
```

It seems to me that there's a sequence (an order) in running methods as such.

Could someone explain that logic and execution sequence for extended range of all string methods please?

Comment: It's executed in the order you write them.

Comment: You can't use  `.upper()` on a list, since the `.split()` function splits all the words according to whitespaces and puts each word in a list. You can only use `.upper()` on strings, so that's why you have to put the `.upper()` first and the `.split()` second

Comment: thank you @RIPPLR clear answer and to the point

Comment: No problem @afii_palang glad to help ;)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's answered in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It executes from left to right. As Torxed mentioned, in the order you write them.

So for instance, `teststr.upper()` returns a String object that has been converted to uppercase. That string object has the method `split()`, so it works just fine.

`teststr.split()` returns a list of string objects. A list doesn't have the `upper()` method, so it fails.

You could, however, do something like:

```py
print([s.upper() for s in teststr.split()])
```

Comment: You should use the code sample formatting for that last big of code in your answer or else it's mumbo jumbo.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @RIPPLR

Comment: No problem ;) @Kyle Cochran

Comment: thanks @Kyle-cochran alternative solution looks cool too

Answer (score 1):

They're executed from left to right.

```
result = variable.fun1().fun2().fun3()
```

is equivalent to

```
temp1 = variable.fun1()
temp2 = temp1.fun2()
result = temp2.fun3()
```